# subfunctions in vim

Tags: function, vim

I created a lot of functions in menu.vim.

I noted that in many functions the same code is used that's why I decided to clean up my file with the use of
subfunctions.

p.e this is code what often returns in my functions:

```
let zoek = @/    
if a:type == "'<,'>"    
 let r = substitute(zoek, '\\%V', '', 'g')    
elseif a:type == "%"    
 let r = zoek    
endif    

let a = substitute(r, '\', '', 'g')      

if matchstr(d, '>') == '>' || matchstr(d, '<') == '<'     
 let e = substitute(d, '\zs>\(\d\+\)%<\ze', '\1-', 'g')     
endif
```

How can I create a subfunction from it?  How can I invoke it?
Does Vim have subfunctions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have «local» functions by defining them in the dictionary: in the following code

```
function MyFunc()
    let d={}
    function d.function()
        echo "Foo"
    endfunction
    call d.function()
endfunction
```

function `d.function` is accessible only inside s:MyFunc and is destroyed after s:MyFunc exits. I put «local» in quotes because `d.function` is really global function named `42` (or another number, it does not matter). <s>It cannot be called without a reference to it and</s> the only way to create a reference is to use `function dict.key()` (references may be copied after creation, but you can't create a reference using call to `function()`, though it is possible for `MyFunc`: `function("MyFunc")`). Note that number (in this case 42) is incremented each time you create a function and I know neither what is the maximum number nor what will happen when it will be reached. I personally use dictionary functions because they have two other advantages:

1. Dictionary function defined inside a script-local dictionary cannot be reached without a debugger or explicit passing the function reference (possibly as a part of its container) somewhere.
2. If more then one function is defined inside a dictionary in order to purge them all you need is to unlet this dictionary. Useful for reloading plugins.

Comment: thank you, is it possible also to import a value from a subfunction using the g:variable and unlet it at the end of the function or isn't it possible to unlet g:variables?

Comment: @Remonn. Yes on both questions, but why you can't just return value that needs to be imported? // Even if you can't, try not to pollute global scope, use `s:variable`. /// There is another hint: inside a function there is a `l:` dictionary that contains all function-local variables. You can pass it to subfunction and modify there in some fashion.

Comment: can you give an example how to pass a list as a l:list to a subfunction (which is exterior the actual function) and how to import it again in the function? I use the list "listlines" in many functions but without the g: before it doesn't work.

Comment: @Remonn You can use `function d.subf(list)\n < Do something with a:list here >\n endfunction\n call d.subf(g:listlines)`. You can use `function d.subf(l)\n < a:l will be a dictionary here and you can thus, for example, add variable 'foo' to local scope by using :let a:l.foo="abc" >\n enfunction\n call d.subf(l:)`. You can't add variables to local (`l:`) scope of the function at the point where it is called, you can only define variables as an function arguments (`a:`). It does not work without the `g:` because inside scripts default scope is `g:`, but inside functions it is `l:`.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one type of function in Vimscript, but I'm not sure if this is what you are already using in your menu.vim. A user-defined function is defined thus:

```
    function! MyNewFunction()
        " your code here
    endfunction
```

You can then call this function elsewhere in your scripts (and inside other functions) using

```
    call MyNewFunction()
```

Or set a variable equal to the return value of your function using

```
    let my_variable = MyNewFunction()
```

Of course this is an incredibly simplistic overview, since you say your are already using functions. Much more information, including the use of variables, here:

```
    help user-functions
```

Apologies if I have not answered your question.